# Drools always return null

Tags: drools

I have a .drl file generated from a rule xls:

```
#From row number: 19
rule "check_19"

salience 65517
activation-group "testCheck"
when
    application : Application(eval( isApplicantType(applicantType, "SINGLE")))
    applicant : Applicant(eval(isValid("18")))
then
    result.add("false");
end
```

The drools fires without any errors but the result is always null. The activation group `testCheck` is set to XOR so I'm assuming either one of application or applicant must be true. Can someone explain to me the issue here? Thanks

Comment: The basics of conditional elements and rule evaluation demand that all patterns in a condition must match: your assumption is not correct.

Comment: Thank you. If you say "all patterns in a condition must match" did you mean applicant and application must be both true or false?

Comment: By "all patterns" I do and did mean all patterns. And "a pattern matches" is just a shorthand for "all constraints of a pattern are true". - Seriously: did you ever read the manual?

Comment: Thanks all good now. I didn't read the manual, that's how good I am  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)